# Why the execution of my code gets stuck as it encounters the function call?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a function named `calculateFaceLocation()`. And I am trying to call `calculateFaceLocation()` from another function named `onButtonClick()`. But the execution gets stopped as soon as the function call line is encountered. I have proved this by using `console.log()`

```
calculateFaceLocation = (response) =>{
 console.log('I HAVE BEAEN CALLED');
}

onButtonClick =(event) =>{

 this.setState({
   ImageUrl:this.state.input
 })
 app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input).then(
   function(response) {
     // do something with response
     console.log(response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box)
     this.calculateFaceLocation();

     console.log('returning after call')
   },
   function(err) {
     // there was an error
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, JavaScript functions will not have the context (`this`) in which they were called. You can either bind the context to the functions using `bind()`, or, the easier way: use arrow functions instead of normal anonymous functions, just like you did when creating `onButtonClick`.

Arrow functions preserve the context they were called in, so the `this` inside the function will the same as whatever it was in that block.

You'd end up with something like
onButtonClick =(event) =>{

```
 this.setState({
   ImageUrl:this.state.input
 })
 app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input).then(
   (response) => {
     // do something with response
     console.log(response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box)
     this.calculateFaceLocation();

     console.log('returning after call')
   },
   (err) => {
     // there was an error
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reason:

Context. Using `this` in a function will refer only to the function from where it is called.

### Explanation:

In your code, the function `calculateFaceLocation` is declared in the parent context and hence it is not accessible from the child function's `this`.

### Solution:

- You can bind the value of `this` in the child funciton using `bind`.
- You can use arrow functions which does this for you.

### Bind Variable Examples:

```
var module = {
    sayHello: function() {
        return "Hello";
    },
    sayHelloName: function(name) {
        return this.sayHello() + " " + name; 
    }
};

console.log(module.sayHelloName('Ram')); // Prints Hello Ram

// Now, Lets pass it to another function like in your code.


// This funciton is bound with the context of module. 
// So accessing sayHello will work.
boundSayHelloName = module.sayHelloName.bind(module); 

// This function doesn't have access to the sayHello function. 
// It will throw Error. 
unboundSayHelloName = module.sayHelloName; 

console.log(boundSayHelloName('Ram')); // Prints Hello Ram
console.log(unboundSayHelloName()); // Throws Error
```

### Code - Using arrow function:

```
calculateFaceLocation = (response) => {
    console.log('I HAVE BEAEN CALLED');
}

onButtonClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        ImageUrl:this.state.input
    })
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input).then(
        (response) => {
            // do something with response
            console.log(response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box)
            this.calculateFaceLocation();

            console.log('returning after call')
        },
        (err) => {
            // there was an error
        }
    );
}
```